# How to build third-party Geany plugins?

Tags: make, json, plugin, geany

After downloading and extracting Geany's [JSON Prettifier](https://plugins.geany.org/jsonprettifier.html), and installing `yajl`, the `make` command does raise this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
./geany_json_prettifier.c:32:25: fatal error: geanyplugin.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

What is left in the system's configuration or `Makefile` to make it work?

Update: under Lubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please add to your question Unix version/Linux distribution you are using and version.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Done: Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: Does `apt install geany-plugin-devhelp` solves your problem? Not quite sure about it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not really, the error persists after this install. `JSON Prettifier` is a third-party plugin, you have to deal with it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer, but:
You can use external formatter:
Edit > Format > Send Selection to > Set Custom Command
like python -m json.tool

[idea stolen from](https://subhadipsblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/23/opening-large-json-files-with-geany/)

Answer (score 2):

Try with :

> apt install libgtk2.0-dev

That's working for me

Answer (score 2):

using ubuntu 20.10 and geany is gtk3 oriented, libgtk2.0-dev doesn't work so install libgtk-3-dev instead:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev`

from [here](https://github.com/imakin/geany-openrelative-plugin/blob/master/README.md)